# (Frenet Formula) Show that exist a function $ω:I \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ satisfying

Tags: differential-geometry

$\alpha:I \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ a curve parametrized by arc lenght, with curvature $k(s)>0$. Show that exist a function $ω:I \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ satisfying

$T′(s)=ω(s)×T(s)$

$N′(s)=ω(s)×N(s)$

$B′(s)=ω(s)×B(s)$

Where $ω(s)$ is angular speed of $\alpha$ in $s$.

I know this is another way to write frenet formulas, but how can prove it?

Comment: It doesn't look like you've tried very hard. What does "where $\omega(s)$ is angular speed of $\alpha$" mean? $\omega$ is a *vector* function, and it encodes the rotation of the entire orthonormal frame $T,N,B$ as $s$ varies. At any rate, write down the Frenet formulas yourself and try to figure it out.

Comment: The frenet formulas involves inner product, and not vectorial product, as appears in the question, I'm stuck...

Comment: No, there's no inner product in the *statement* of the Frenet formulas, only in the proof.